# manipulate name of (first) chunk in webpack?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, webpack

It may be a weirdo question, but the story behind this is:

We want to split code within a wordpress project - with my current knowledge you have to be specific with importing a JS file to wordpress - thats why the initial file should have a static name

***plugin.php***

```
...
plugins_url('dist/index.js',__FILE__ ),
...
```

with a webpack config like this:

***webpack.config.js***

```
...
entry: {
    index: ["@babel/polyfill", path.join( __dirname, 'src/index.tsx' )],
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    publicPath: '/'
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
    }
},
...
```

it should do the job, but is it possible to also add a hash to only the following splitchunks?

with a configuration like this:

***webpack.config.js***

```
entry: {
    index: ["@babel/polyfill", path.join( __dirname, 'src/index.tsx' )],
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',             // ONLY LINE CHANGED
    path: path.resolve( __dirname, 'dist' ),
    publicPath: '/'
},
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all'
    }
},
```

all files get the hash

any suggestions? :/

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify non-entry chunks' names you could use [`output.chunkFilename`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputchunkfilename) instead.

Ultimately you could provide a function as a `output.filename` and implement whatever logic you need.

From docs

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    filename: (chunkData) => {
      return chunkData.chunk.name === 'main' ? '[name].js': '[name]/[name].js';
    },
  }
};
```